# How to highlight when object is selected?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am coming to a issue where I need help to highlight an object when the object is selected. I tried by importing a circle image icon and try to create in c# script, but that does not quite work well. So, can anyone help me to solve it (differently, if possible) or improve my code in order to make this work. thanks for the help. Let me know if I need to elaborate more. thanks!

Here is my code:

```
public void Editcomponents()
{ 
    ClearText();
    CircleImageStatus = !CircleImageStatus;
    var imgs = reticle.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>(true);
    if (CircleImageStatus)
    { 
        foreach (var img in imgs)
        {
            img.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(235, 210, 52, 255);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var img in imgs)
        {
            img.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(255, 255, 255, 255); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question sounds more like a general design question not a specific implementation issue. This would be to broad for this community...

Answer (score 0):

There is this asset that makes an outline for your object:

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/fullscreen-camera-effects/outline-effect-78608

I used it before and its simple and awesome.

Usage:
You can just enable and disable the Outline script on the object

If you would still like to use stuff like a circle, you can use GUI items and move them to the objects position with WorldToScreen transforms https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html

Comment: can the outline effect work when I select on the object?

Comment: yes :D you just call some function it's pretty simple

Comment: Will edit my answer in a couple of minutes once i download the asset and will give a better explanation

Comment: There we go :D Updated

Comment: So, if I have multiple object do I need add the `Outline` script to every object, right?

Comment: Yes, you can look at a script to see what is going on, its pretty simple :D

Comment: yes, but with my code above thats the method I am calling to select the object.  So, I  have a edit button where when the user clicks on the edit it lets the user edit as in to select, and when I select a object - I want that to highlight (meaning to call the Outline script)

Comment: Wait, are these GUI elements?

Comment: Hahahahaha this doesn't work for GUI elements, let me think of a better solution

Comment: So, I selected the element and add the outline script to it. and okay.

Comment: I posted another answer

Answer (score 0):

For a GUI element you can use this built in Outline script : 
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Outline.html
to show an outline around the object which you can toggle on and off for selection purpocess :D